# Powershell: Find all nested groups

Tags: powershell, recursion, active-directory

Using get-adgroupmember to find the immediate members of a group is well-known. Likewise, adding the -recursive parameter is a well-known way to find all users that are members of a group. Is there a way to find all *groups* that are members of a group?

Background: One of my customers have had a nasty habit of using nested groups for access management. The worst case sees six levels of nested groups, each level having a significant number of groups as members.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/santisq/Get-Hierarchy it's pretty old but afaik it still works

Answer (score 2):

**Revised answer**

Unfortunately, using `Get-ADGroupMember` together with switch `-Recursive` will **not** return members that are groups.
As [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps#description) state:

> If the Recursive parameter is specified, the cmdlet gets all members
> in the hierarchy of the group that do not contain child objects.

To get an array of nested group objects within a certain parent group, you will need a recursive function like below (untested):

```
function Get-NestedADGroup {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Alias('Group')]
        # any of Name, DistinguishedName, objectGUID, objectSid, sAMAccountName
        [string]$Identity,

        # optional parameters
        [string[]]$Properties = @(),
        [string]$Server = $null,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        # This allows you to pass in a username as a string and have an interactive prompt for the password
        [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty
    )

    # Get-ADGroup by default returns properties DistinguishedName, GroupCategory, GroupScope, Name, ObjectClass, 
    # ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID. This function always adds property Members to that.
    # (PowerShell property name: Members; LDAP attribute name: member)
    $params = @{
        Identity   = $Identity
        Properties = @($Properties) + 'Members' | Sort-Object -Unique  
    }  
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Server)) { $params['Server'] = $Server }
    if (($Credential) -and $Credential -ne [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty) {
        $params['Credential'] = $Credential
    }

    # try and get the group object from AD
    $adGroup = Get-ADGroup @params -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($adGroup) {
        if (-not $script:groupsHash.ContainsKey($adGroup.DistinguishedName)) {
            # output this group object
            $adGroup
            # add the DistinguishedName of this group to the hash to prevent circular references
            $script:groupsHash[$adGroup.DistinguishedName] = $true
            # loop through the groups Members collection (all DistinguishedNames)
            foreach ($member in $adGroup.Members){
                $params['Identity'] = $member  # reuse the params Hashtable
                $params.Remove('Properties')   # remove Properties from the Hashtable for Get-ADObject
                $memberObject = Get-ADObject @params -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                if (($memberObject) -and $memberObject.objectClass -eq 'group') {
                    # recurse to get the nested groups
                    $params['Properties'] = $Properties  # add the Properties to the Hashtable again
                    Get-NestedADGroup @params
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Group '$($Identity)' could not be found.."
    }
}

# create a Hashtable to avoid circular nested groups
$groupsHash = @{}

# call the function
$result = Get-NestedADGroup -Group 'TheGroupToInspect'

# output just the names
$result.Name
```

Comment: Sadly, that returned nothing.

Comment: @razumny Please see my revised answer. I couldn't test this just yet, so please let me know?

Comment: My apologies for a late response; I'm getting the following error:

Get-ADGroup : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:22 char:16
+     $adGroup = Get-ADGroup (a)params
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADGroup], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup
 
WARNING: Group 'Group To Be Checked' could not be found..

Comment: @razumny Sorry, I mixed-up the parameter sets.. Should be fixed now

Comment: New and exciting error messages:

Get-ADObject : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist
Parameter name: Members
At C:\path\Script\Get-NestedADGroup.ps1:42 char:33
+ ...    $memberObject = Get-ADObject @params -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (CN=NAME,DC=TLD:ADObject) [Get-ADObject], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADObject

Comment: @razumny What is `TLD` (Top Level Domain) doing in the DistinguishedName ?? Instead of `$memberObject = Get-ADObject @params -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` you could use a `try { $memberObject = Get-ADObject @params -ErrorAction Stop`; ...} {catch {}` there, but I have never seen that before myself..

Comment: @razumny This may have to do with the 'Properties' that may not be available for Get-ADObject. I have added `$params.Remove('Properties')` now because we don't need any there except for the default ones, then re-add it to start the next recursion

Answer (score 2):

Another take to [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74478184/15339544) using a [`Stack<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=net-7.0) instead of recursion.

**Note, this function will output unique objects, i.e.: if a user was a member of more than one nested group, said user will be only outputted once (same applies for any `ObjectClass`).**

```bash
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
using namespace Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management

function Get-ADGroupMemberRecursive {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [Alias('DistinguishedName')]
        [string] $Identity,

        [Parameter()]
        [string[]] $Properties,

        [Parameter()]
        [string] $Server
    )

    begin {
        class IdentityHelper {
            hidden [hashtable] $domainmap = @{}
            hidden [hashtable] $cache = @{}

            [void] Add([object] $object) {
                $this.cache.Add($object.distinguishedName, $object)
            }

            [object] Get([string] $distinguishedName, [hashtable] $properties) {
                if ($this.cache.ContainsKey($distinguishedName)) {
                    return $this.cache[$distinguishedName]
                }

                $obj = Get-ADObject $distinguishedName @properties
                $this.Add($obj)
                return $obj
            }

            [object] TryGet([string] $distinguishedName, [hashtable] $properties) {
                $domain = $distinguishedName -replace '^.+?(?=DC=)'

                if (-not $this.domainmap.ContainsKey($domain)) {
                    $this.domainmap[$domain] = [adsi]::new('LDAP://' + $domain).InvokeGet('dc')
                }

                $obj = Get-ADObject $distinguishedName @properties -Server $this.domainmap[$domain]
                $this.Add($obj)
                return $obj
            }
        }

        $adObjParams = @{ Properties = @('Member') }

        if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Properties')) {
            $adObjParams['Properties'] += $Properties | Sort-Object -Unique
        }

        if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Server')) {
            $adObjParams['Server'] = $Server
        }

        $hash = [HashSet[guid]]::new()
        $stack = [Stack[ADObject]]::new()
        $helper = [IdentityHelper]::new()
    }

    process {
        try {
            $group = Get-ADGroup $Identity @adObjParams
        }
        catch {
            $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
            return
        }

        $stack.Push($group)
        while ($stack.Count) {
            $group = $stack.Pop()

            foreach ($member in $group.member) {
                try {
                    $obj = $helper.Get($member, $adObjParams)
                }
                catch {
                    # member might be in a different domain
                    $e = $_

                    try {
                        # attempt to query the identity in this domain
                        $helper.TryGet($member, $adObjParams)
                    }
                    catch {
                        # if failed, fallback
                        $PSCmdlet.WriteError($e)
                        continue
                    }
                }

                $obj

                if ($obj.objectClass -eq 'group' -and $hash.Add($obj.objectGuid)) {
                    $stack.Push($obj)
                }
            }
        }

        $hash.Clear()
    }
}
```

Usage is fairly straight forward:

```bash
# positional binding
Get-ADGroupMemberRecursive groupNameHere

# or through pipeline
Get-ADGroup groupNameHere | Get-ADGroupMemberRecursive
```