# Active Directory - list full subgroup dependency of a given group and omit subgroups without any user

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, usergroups, dsquery

I have to list full subgroup dependency of specific group - filter -> only subgroups which contain at least 1 user.

I have tried this approach:

```
dsquery group -samid <specific_group> | dsget group -members -expand  | dsquery * -filter "(&(objectclass=group))"
```

Comment: Do you have access to the PowerShell ActiveDirectory Module?

Comment: Yes, I have access.

Comment: What about groups that may have a member other than a user? i.e. a gMSA account or that's not a possibility?

Comment: I need only for users

Answer (score 0):

This is an adapted version of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74478184/9898643) to omit groups without any user object.

Unfortunately, using `Get-ADGroupMember` together with switch `-Recursive` will **not** return members that are groups.
As [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps#description) state:

> If the Recursive parameter is specified, the cmdlet gets all members
> in the hierarchy of the group that do not contain child objects.

To get an array of nested group objects within a certain parent group, you will need a recursive function like below:

```
function Get-NestedADGroup {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Alias ('Identity')]
        [string]$Group,
        # the other parameters are optional
        [string]$Server      = $null,
        [string]$SearchBase  = $null,
        [ValidateSet('Base', 'OneLevel', 'Subtree')]
        [string]$SearchScope = 'Subtree'
    )

    $params = @{
        Identity    = $Group
        SearchScope = $SearchScope
        Properties  = 'Members'
        ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
    }  
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Server))     { $params['Server'] = $Server }
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SearchBase)) { $params['SearchBase'] = $SearchBase }

    $adGroup = Get-ADGroup @params
    if ($adGroup) {
        if (-not $script:groupsHash.ContainsKey($Group)) {
            # output this group object only if it has at least one user object
            if (@($adGroup.Members | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'user'}).Count -gt 0) {
                $adGroup
            }
            # avoid circular group references
            $script:groupsHash[$Group] = $true
            # and recurse to get the nested groups
            foreach ($group in ($adGroup.Members | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'group'})) {
                Get-NestedADGroup -Group $group.DistinguishedName -Server $Server -SearchBase $SearchBase
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Group '$($Group)' could not be found.."
    }
}

# create a Hashtable to avoid circular nested groups
$groupsHash = @{}

# call the function
$result = Get-NestedADGroup -Group 'SpecificGroup'

# output just the names if you like
$result.Name

# save to CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\SubgroupsWithAtLeastOneUser.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Could you please describe me how and where could i include it?

Comment: @Doublementi Include into what? This is simple the whole code, you only have to change `'SpecificGroup'` into the name or preferrably the DistinguishedName of the parent group to work on in line `$result = Get-NestedADGroup -Group 'SpecificGroup'`

Comment: I've got error: 'WARNING: Group '<my_group_name>' could not be found..', Do the DC:<company_name> DC<com> should be specified, or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @Doublementi No, just use the correct name of the group. If in doubt, open ADUC, search for the group, klick properties and copy the DistinghuishedName of the group. Then use that when calling the function

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy alternative leveraging [Active Directory filtering capabilities](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)). See inline comments to understand the logic.

**Do note, this answer requires the [ActiveDirectory Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/?view=windowsserver2022-ps) available.**

```bash
# Get the DN of the parent group (this is the initial group)
$parent = (Get-ADGroup parentGroup).distinguishedName
$param = @{
    LDAPFilter = "(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$parent)"
    Properties = "member"
}
# Find, recursively, all child groups Members Of this parent group
# and filter
Get-ADGroup @param | Where-Object {
    # For each member of this child group,
    # check if this member is an object of the Class `user`,
    # if it is, we already can break the pipeline and return
    # this child group, since we already know it has
    # at least 1 user member
    $_.member | Get-ADObject | Where-Object ObjectClass -EQ user |
        Select-Object -First 1
}
```

Comment: I need to list full subgroup dependency - if subgroup which not have users, has groups, then go inside each group and check if users are there, if yes, save the name, next, if in saved group are still subgroups beyond the users, go inside all of them, and check it each time, deeper and deeper, till reach the core of this group dependency.

Comment: @Doublementi not the premise of your question